# Not able to open the `Modal` from Header link using common service

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

I have a `service` for `modal` purpose. it works fine, when i click on a button in the body. but it's not working when i call from the header.

I am included the service in both case.

please look the `demo` for clear understanding.

[Live Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/xn2LTCQdtdeAZiRfzTOy?p=preview)

Here is the code :

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

  app.service('modalService', function() {
      this.width  = 100;
      this.height  = 100;
  });

  app.directive('modalDialog', function(modalService) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      show: '='
    },
    replace: true, // Replace with the template below
    transclude: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.dialogStyle = {};
      if (modalService.width != 0)
        scope.dialogStyle.width = modalService.width;
      if (modalService.height != 0)
        scope.dialogStyle.height = modalService.height;

      scope.hideModal = function() {
        scope.show = false;
        modalService.modalContent = '';
      };

    },
    templateUrl: "modal.html"
  };
});

app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'modalService', function($scope, modalService) {
  $scope.modalShown = false;
  $scope.modalService = modalService;

  $scope.toggleModal = function() {
    console.log(modalService);
    $scope.modalService.modalContent = 'It works';
    $scope.modalShown = !$scope.modalShown; //works here.
  };

}]); 

app.controller('header', ['$scope', 'modalService', function($scope, modalService) {

  $scope.toggleModal = function() {
    console.log(modalService);
    $scope.modalShown = !$scope.modalShown; //not working from here
  };

}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I check your plunker and it seems you do not add template to your html code for ng-controller="header"

add this :

```
<modal-dialog show="modalShown" width='400px' height='60%'>
   <p>{{modalService.modalContent}}<p>
</modal-dialog>
```

and your html should be like this :

```
<div class="header" ng-controller="header">
  <ul>
    <li><a ng-click="toggleModal()" href="">Link1</a></li>
    <li><a ng-click="toggleModal()" href="">Link2</a></li>
  </ul>
  <modal-dialog show="modalShown" width='400px' height='60%'>
   <p>{{modalService.modalContent}}<p>
</modal-dialog>
</div>
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<button ng-click="toggleModal()">Open Modal Dialog</button>
<modal-dialog show="modalShown" width='400px' height='60%'>
   <p>{{modalService.modalContent}}<p>
</modal-dialog>
```

Comment: @3gwebtrain, sure here it is [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/HTgLO723TLzRNM5OcDJx?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Basically the problem is you're trying to open a modal from a different (and parallel) scope. The scope of `header` is different from the scope of `MyCtrl`. So you can't change modalShown of `MyCtrl` inside of `header`.

Your approach using a service is correct, as services are singletons, and can share code between two controllers. Only you need to create an API in the modalService to open the modal and close it.

I've tried to figure out a quick solution. This is a simple approach to illustrate my solution:

```
[...]

app.service('modalService', function() {

  this.width  = 100;
  this.height  = 100;

  // Our simple listener array
  var listeners = [];

  // Add an api method to toggle
  this.toggle = function(){
    if (listeners.length) {
      for (var i=0; i<listeners.length; i++) {
        listeners[i].call(this);
      }
    }
  };

  // Add listener function
  this.addListener = function(cb){
    listeners.push(cb);
  };
});

app.directive('modalDialog', function(modalService) {

  return {
    [...]
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      [...]

      // This function allows us to change the scope var from outside
      modalService.addListener(function(){
        scope.show = !scope.show;
      });

      [...]
    },
    [...]
  };
});

app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'modalService', function($scope, modalService) {
  [...]

  $scope.toggleModal = function() {
    $scope.modalService.modalContent = 'It works';

    // Toggle the modal via api method
    console.log(modalService);
    modalService.toggle();
  };

}]); 

app.controller('header', ['$scope', 'modalService', function($scope, modalService) {

  $scope.toggleModal = function() {
    // Toggle the modal via api method
    console.log(modalService);
    modalService.toggle();
  };

}]);
```

Here's an updated plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/PErrDD41wRu3Kvyncx45?p=preview

If you need more explanation, just comment, I'll add some if possible.

Comment: How to add different content each of the popup using `ng-include`

Comment: And anther thing is, I just want to open the modal from header alone, the `MyCtrl` not require to open it. In that case how we do?

Comment: "Different content" is difficult to solve with ng-include because you only have one modal instance at the moment. You could load it via $http, if you need to load it dynamically. But I suggest you take a look at ui-bootstrap's modals (https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal). They have most of the stuff you need, plus resolve dynamic content with promises

Comment: The other comment, about the just calling from the header, just remove $scope.toggleModal from MyCtrl.